# Parse Server S3 Adaptor saves image as .txt

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-s3, parse-server

I am using the S3 adaptor to save images to my S3 bucket. My client code is:

```
var saveFileToParse = function(imageData) {
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(Parse.User.current().id + " Image", {
        base64: imageData
    });
    $ionicLoading.show();
    parseFile.save().then(function(response) {

        if (angular.isNumber($scope.activeExercise.images[0])) {
            $scope.activeExercise.images = [];
        }

        var imageUrl = response._url;
        $scope.activeExercise.images.push(imageUrl);

        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.customImage = true;

        $ionicLoading.hide();

    }).then(function(imageUrl) {

            var file = new Parse.Object("Files");
            file.set("file", parseFile);

            file.save().then(function(response) {

                $ionicLoading.hide();

            });

        },
        function(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();

            errorFactory.checkError(error);

        });
};
```

The file is being saved, however is being saved as a `.txt` file, I expect because of the base 64, however this was never an issue on parse.com. Can I explicitly make this save as .jpg?

EDIT:

I am employed the code below and this gives a different filename and shows as an image in S3. However, when downloaded it still has a .txt file extension. I have even changed my save command to include the mime-type `var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file, "image/jpeg");`

[image: S3 example]

Comment: Oh dear, you are using parse API and hope it works against AWS S3 without specify any target changes? S3 is just an GIGO store, if your API send BASE64, it will not transform it.

Comment: Indeed! There isn't any documentation to the contrary!

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  It seems you need to switch `3. a File object selected with a file upload control.` 
https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.File.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you just need to [read the documentation thoroughly](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.File.html). The answer is already available there, so just pass the file object.

```
var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
    var name = "photo.jpg";
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
    parseFile.save().then(function () {
        // The file has been saved to Parse.
    }, function (error) {
        // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was caused by the old parse.com server automatically applying %20 when there was a space in the file URL.

Removing the space made it work.